# Windows 8 app dev JavaScript - Show/Hide Div in JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm trying to show or hide divs based on user settings in a Windows 8 app. I have 2 divs in my html file:

```
<div id="fillBlank"><p>Fill in the Blank area</p></div>
<div id="multipleChoice"><p>Multiple choice area</p></div>
```

In the JavaScript file I have:

```
var answerStyle = "mc";

function showArea() {
    if (answerStyle == "mc") {
        // Multiple choice
        multipleChoice.visible = true;
        fillBlank.visible = false;
    } else if (answerStyle == "fb") {
        // Fill in the blank
        multipleChoice.visible = false;
        fillBlank.visible = true;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in JavaScript is to use the style property:

```
var fillBlank = document.getElementById("fillBlank");    
fillBlank.style.display = "none";
```

Setting style.display to "" will make it visible using what ever the display time the element currently has set.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close!

```
var answerStyle = "mc";

function showArea() {
    if (answerStyle == "mc") {
        // Multiple choice
        multipleChoice.style.visibility ='visible';
        fillBlank.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (answerStyle == "fb") {
        // Fill in the blank
        multipleChoice.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        fillBlank.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```